# html ¿como adaptar el tamaño de la fuente de un texto dentro de un div a sus dimensiones?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Buen día.
Tengo un contenedor que ocupa el 50% a lo ancho y a lo alto, dentro de este tengo un párrafo, al re-dimensionar el div (redimesionando la ventana del navegador) el toma sus porcentajes deacuerdo al tamaño de la ventana, por lo que si le doy a la fuente del parrafo un tamaño fijo se desborda en algunos tamaños de ventana.¿que propiedad, propiedades o libreria debo usar para arreglar este problema?. De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Según lo que leo en la pregunta voy a asumir que el contenedor ocupa siempre el 50% del alto/ancho del viewport.

En ese orden de ideas lo más fácil sería utilizar la unidad de medida `vw` (viewport width), en la cual cada unidad equivale a un punto en % del ancho de la zona visible:

```css
.container {
  border: solid 1px blue;
  width: 50%;
}

p {
  font-size: 3vw; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>
    ¡Hola mundo!
  </p>
</div>
```

En este ejemplo le asignamos un tamaño a la fuente de 3% del ancho del viewport, de tal forma se adaptará a cualquier resolución de pantalla, de forma proporcional.

Hay técnicas más avanzadas con calc() y las unidades de medida vw, pero creo que no están dentro de lo que se pregunta.

Comment: muchas gracias, tu respuesta soluciono el problema

Answer (score 1):

Para adaptar los estilos a las dimensiones deberias evaluar implementar `media queries`

[CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

[CSS3 Media Queries - Examples](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

como observaras puedes definir estilos que aplicaran segun las dimensiones de la pantalla

```
@media (min-width: 700px) { ... }
```

en los ... defines el estilo que quieres que aplique cuando el minimo sea de 700px, esto es un ejemplo simple pero puede armar cosas mas complejas